# Formatos de Entrada vs Formatos de Salida Excel para importacion

Tags: excel

necesito realizar una importación de un archivo CSV en un sistema (odoo). El sistema es lo de menos en este momento.

Sere lo mas breve posible.

Actualmente estoy recibiendo datos de parte de un cliente de la siguiente forma:

[image: Imagen de datos de entrada]

Sin embargo, el sistema me pide que la forma de entrada de los datos sea la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Es posible llevar el formato de entrada al formato de salida mediante Excel?

**Explicación de los datos:**

ci: Numero de identificación de una persona
rs = 8007 / 8009 / 8013 / 8200: Son claves de asignaciones y deducciones (dinero que entra y sale)

Por la comodidad el cliente envía los datos de la forma de la imagen de entrada (1). Pero el sistema los pide con el formato de salida.

**Que el cliente no cambie su formato de entrada no es una alternativa según palabras propias de la contratista.**

Comment: De una forma sencilla no. Tendrás que utilizar VBA para programar una rutina que formatee los datos como necesitas.

Comment: Tendrás que ir transponiendo tus datos. Lo puedes hacer a mano o intentar programarte algo en VBA

Comment: A mano no es una opcion. No existe una forma que sea sin tener que adquirir conocimientos en VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando Power Query, siguiendo estos pasos:

1. Datos > Obtener datos > Desde otras fuentes > Consulta en blanco

   [image: Power Query]

   Eso abre el editor de Power Query
2. Dentro del editor,

   Vista > Editor avanzado

   [image: Editor de PQ]
3. Reemplazar *todo* el texto del editor por el siguiente código (comentado):

   - Hay que modificar la ruta del CSV en la segunda línea (también el delimitador si no está dividido por comas)

     ```
     let
        //tomar del CSV
        Origen = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\la\ruta\completa\de\TuArchivo.csv"),[Delimiter=","]),
        //usar la 1ra fila de encabezados
        Headers = Table.PromoteHeaders(Origen, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
        //despivotear todo menos la columna "ci", llevando nombres de columnas a la columna "rs" y valores a la columna "amount"
        Unpivot = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Headers, {"ci"}, "rs", "amount"),
        //agrupar por "ci", poniendo un contador de fila a cada uno
        GroupBy = Table.Group(Unpivot, {"ci"}, {{"Data", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "index",1), type table}}),
        //expandir para volver a toda la tabla con el contador
        Expand = Table.ExpandTableColumn(GroupBy, "Data", {"rs", "amount", "index"}),
        //cambiar el nombre de "ci" por uno auxiliar
        repe = Table.RenameColumns(Expand,{{"ci", "ci_repetidos"}}),
        //generar nueva columna "ci" sólo para la fila 1 de c/u
        ci = Table.AddColumn(repe, "ci", each if [index] = 1 then [ci_repetidos] else null),
        //quedarse sólo con las 3 columnas que queremos
        final = Table.SelectColumns(ci,{"ci", "rs", "amount"})
     in
        final
     ```
4. Aceptar (cierra el editor avanzado)
5. Cerrar y cargar

Esto trae los datos en una nueva hoja, con una nueva tabla en el formato que querías:

[image: final]

---

**Además**, podrías grabar este Excel y reutilizarlo para el CSV que quieras, sólo hay que cambiarle el origen a la consulta de Power Query en: Datos > Obtener datos > Configuración del origen de datos...